# typescript null safe destructure

Tags: typescript

I have typed graphql queries that can be deep objects where every level can be nullable which makes my destructuring code look pretty bad...

```
const { levelOne } = data || {} as keyof typeof data;
conse { levelTwo } = levelOne || {} as keyof typeof levelOne;
...
```

can I make this cleaner by providing a null safe destructure function...

```
const safeDestructure = <T extends {}>(obj:T): T => {
  return obj || {} as keyof typeof obj;
}
```

or is there a better way to do either the inline destructuring or the safe destructure function?

Comment: try using the lodash `_.get()` function to safely get a property.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Comment: I don't get why you're doing `as keyof typeof data`.  Do you use `--strictNullChecks`?  If `data` is possibly `null` then `data || {}` is of type something like `NonNullable<typeof data> | {}` , not `keyof` anything.